# Select anyone of the radio button in a radio group using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in terms of Javascript.

There are lot of similar questions in Stackoverflow. But none of that solve my this small example.

I like to select a particular radio button by default using only javascript.

I tried this below simple example in my localhost. But it didn't work. It is selecting the last radio button

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <form name="myform" action="">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
                <br>
                    <label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="First">First</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Second">Second</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Third">Third</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fourth">Fourth</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fifth">Fifth</input>
                <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rates = document.getElementsByName('radio_value');
            var rate_value;
            for(var i = 0; i < rates.length; i++){
                document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[i].checked=true;
            }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check out the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L16tgvn0/7/)
Sorry friends, I can't add id to each radio button.

Comment: you not include `jquery` but use `$(document)`, i think you are got error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Will change the code shortly. Please wait.

Comment: for what you need check it with javascript, you can set attr `checked` in first element, it's enough

Comment: That `label`'s `for` attr should reference an `id`, _not_ a `name`. Each radio input needs its own label and the labels should be on the *right* of the inputs.

Comment: You don’t say *which* radio button should be set. In your own answer, you set the *second* radio button, which might be what you were thinking, but the question as asked is not answerable. There are several ways to refer to a radio button element, but you need to give some definition that unambiguously identifies which one should be set.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I can't particularly set a radio button, In my program, I can set the radio button based on other variable. So based on the value of the variable, I need to set the radio button as checked.

Comment: What variable? How does it relate to the HTML markup?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It is for a PHP Project. But I believe the base is right here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve it.

```
document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[1].checked=true;
```

My updated [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L16tgvn0/4/)

Answer (score 4):

you can use: `document.getElementById("First")` and set the `checked` to `true`.

```
document.getElementById("First").checked = true;
```

---

**[Updated]**  Try something like:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].type === 'radio') radios[i].checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I can't use id for each radio button.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this is very simply with jquery:

```
$("#First").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk1p8cj/)

**UPDATE**

Then go with nash_ag's vanilla javascript, which is the simplest way to do this:

```
document.getElementById("First").checked = true;
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk1p8cj/1/)

Comment: Please I need to use only javascript. I already know the solution which uses jquery.

Comment: Sorry. I can't use id for each radio button.

Comment: @Gunaseelan you should really add all of the requirements into your post before hand so people know what they are working with

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName gives you an array of matching elements. Access a particular element via its index in the DOM, which should be the same as its index in the array. The code in your example iterates through each element in the array, checking it and simultaneously unchecking the previously checked element(this is the behavior of a radio button group).